# Concrete implementations of abstract method

Tags: c#, oop, generics, inheritance

My goal is to hide all details of the classes that I’m building from the client, including which concrete class to instantiate.

The client passes an enum to a factory which returns an instance of the appropriate derived class like so:

```
IAutomobile auto = Autofactory.GetAuto(param);
```

I created a base class that does most of the work, but I need specific derived classes to implement specific logic.

```
public interface IAutomobile
{
    void Rename(string p1, int p2);
}
public abstract class Automobile : IAutomobile
{
    // Lots of properties and methods...

    public abstract void Rename(string p1, int p2);
}

public class Jeep : Automobile
{
    public override void Rename(string p1, int p2)
    {
        // Uses p1 & p2 with the base class
    }
}
```

Now the client can call:

```
auto.Rename("s1", "s2");
```

All is good until of course I create the other derived class which implements the "Rename()" method with a different signature.

```
public class Audi : Automobile
{
    public override void Rename(int i, SomeOtherClass someOtherClass)
    {
        //Does something with params
    }
}
```

This second implementation has a different signature which not surprisingly throws a compile error.

So, I tried to make the parameter passing more "*flexible*" by using a Dictionary like this:

```
public interface IAutomobile
{
    void Rename(Dictionary<object, object> parameters);
}
```

**Client:**

```
public class client
{
    public void Client()
    {
        var parameters = new Dictionary<object, object>();
        IAutomobile auto = AutoFactory.GetFactory();

        parameters.Add("Param1Name", "string1");
        parameters.Add("Param2Name", 21);
        auto.Rename(parameters);
    }
}
```

**Derived Class:**

```
public class Audi : Automobile, IAutomobile
{
    public override void Rename(Dictionary<object, object> parameters)
    {
        //  cast/box/unbox from dictionary objects...
        //  does something unique for Audis...
    }
}
```

So this is how I’ve implemented it with the dictionary where parameters are key/value pairs, but that seems **awful**.  I don’t see how it buys me anything.

Or, I could create object which represents the union of all derived class parameters, but again, that seems terrible.

Can someone suggest a way in which I could arrange this so that casting, boxing and un-boxing are not required?

I don't mind exposing objects to be used with the Rename() method like:

```
auto.Rename(AudiFeatures);
```

or

```
auto.Rename(JeepFeatures);
```

(BTW, I don't really want to pass individual params, I'd like to pass objects)

A client call like this would not work because I'd have to hard code the type in the client code.  I'd like to hard code that in the factory, but then how would I return the correct interface type, and What would the return type of the factory be?

I don't want to do this:

```
IAutomobile<JeepRenamingData> auto = Autofactory.GetAuto<JeepRenamingData>(param);
```

I'd like to do this:

```
IAutomobile auto = Autofactory.GetAuto(param);
auto.Rename(myJeepRenamingData);
```

and have the factory return the correct type:

```
    public static IAuto GetAutomobileManager(AutoMaker manufacturer)
    {
        switch (manufacturer)
        {
            case AutoMaker.Jeep
                return new Jeep<JeepNamingOptions>();

            case AutoMaker.Audi
                return new Audi<AudiNamingOptions>();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Say I do this: `IAutomobile auto = Autofactory.GetAuto(param);`. I don't know what `auto` is, so how should I know if I should pass in `AudiFeatures` or `JeepFeatures`? If I *do* know what `auto` is, what's the point in casting to an interface and/or using the factory? If `Rename` changes signatures, it's a good indication that it doesn't fit the use case for overriding methods.

Comment: And if the user does somehow know which type of Rename to call, then you _could_ create a Rename function with a different signature.  The user would have to cast the Automobile to a concrete class in order to call it, of course.  But knowing what kind of car it is would be necessary anyway, in order to know what kind of Rename to call, no?

Comment: @Chris Berger, This set of classes supports a UI.  The example is contrived to spare you all of the gory details ;) but basically the user indicates a base car either Audi or Jeep, and the callback for that selection can determine which car.  Therefore, it would be known...  I don't want the UI to know the details of the derived class....

Answer (score 1):

The immediate thought is to use generics. Can you do this?

```
public interface IAutomobile { }

public interface IAutomobile<P1, P2> : IAutomobile
{
    void Rename(P1 p1, P2 p2);
}

public abstract class Automobile<P1, P2> : IAutomobile<P1, P2>
{
    // Lots of properties and methods...

    public abstract void Rename(P1 p1, P2 p2);
}

public class Jeep : Automobile<string, int>
{
    public override void Rename(string p1, int p2)
    {
        // Uses p1 & p2 with the base class
    }
}
```

The client call would then look like this:

```
IAutomobile<string, int> auto = Autofactory.GetAuto<string, int>(param);
auto.Rename("Foo", 42);
IAutomobile auto_plain = auto;
```

---

Based on your update, this would be my suggestion now:

```
IAutomobile<JeepFeatures> auto = Autofactory.GetAuto<JeepFeatures>(param);
auto.Rename(new JeepFeatures());
IAutomobile auto_plain = auto;


public interface IAutomobile { }

public interface IAutomobile<P> : IAutomobile
{
    void Rename(P parameters);
}

public abstract class Automobile<P> : IAutomobile<P>
{
    public abstract void Rename(P parameters);
}

public class Jeep : Automobile<JeepFeatures>
{
    public override void Rename(JeepFeatures parameters)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please indicate how the client call would look?  I'm not getting that part.  Would the client call look like: IAutomobile<P1, P2> auto = AutoFactory.GetFactory(param);

Comment: Ok, I'm already passing generic type info from the factory, so it makes sense to pass another type.  I still don't exactly get it, but I'll wrestle with it a little while and then post my results.

Comment: @Dave I have a strong feeling a factory is *not* the right approach here. There doesn't seem to be any benefit of using it in your above example. Reasons being: 1. The user knows what type they're getting back. 2. The objects being returned by the factory do not implement a single interface. Factories are useful when you want to say 'Give me something that is guaranteed to do X. I don't care how it does it, or what it is, as long as it fulfills the contract'.

Comment: @Rob I agree with you, especially about not implementing a single interface.  So it's kind of a force.  But it would be very convenient to use a single object for all of the work that's being done by the UI.  There's probably a better choice of pattern, but that's part of my goal (design better software)

Comment: @Rob I agree with you, especially about not implementing a single interface.  So it's kind of a force.  But it would be very convenient to use a single object for all of the work that's being done by the UI.  There's probably a better choice of pattern, but that's part of my goal (learn to design better software)

Comment: @Dave - I've added the client call. I did make a mistake and left `Rename` in the `IAutomobile` collection. I've now fixed it.

Comment: I just updated my question.  I don't think that the client example you mentioned above would work for me.  Take a look at the end of the updated question.

Comment: @Dave - There's very little difference in the edit you made and what I'm suggesting with my code. You've effectively just removed one parameter.

Comment: @Dave - I've updated my code to show you what I mean.

Comment: Sorry, that first attempt at modifying my question wasn't as clear as it could have been.  Basically, I can't declare or ask for a specific derived type.  I was hoping that a factory could abstract that away, but I don't think that it can.  Which leads me to believe that I've chosen the wrong implementation....

Comment: @Dave - That's probably the case. Can you explain what you're trying to do without the "vehicular" metaphor?

Answer (score 0):

For me, either way your current approach has a design flaw.

While you want to completely hide concrete car details, you're requiring concrete details, because you can't work with a car which you don't know at all... In summary, **I see excessive abstraction**.

Instead of wanting a too abstract interface like `IAutomobile` to manipulate your cars, you should use the power of interfaces to solve your problem from scratch:

```
public interface ICanRename<TArgs>
    where TArgs : class
{
    void Rename(TArgs args);
}

public interface IAutomobile 
{
    // Other common behaviors 
}

public interface IJeep : IAutomobile, ICanRename<JeepRenameArgs>
{
}

public class JeepRenameArgs {}

public class Jeep: IJeep
{
    public void Rename(JeepRenameArgs args)
    {
        // Rename stuff 
    }
}

public class AutomobileFactory
{
    private Dictionary<Type, Type> AutomobileImplementations = new Dictionary<Type, Type>
    {
        { typeof(IJeep), typeof(Jeep) } 
    };

    public TAutomobile Create<TAutomobile>() 
        where TAutomobile : IAutomobile
    {
        TAutomobile automobile = (TAutomobile)Activator.CreateInstance(AutomobileImplementations[typeof(TAutomobile)]);

        // Some initialization stuff here

        return automobile;
    }
}
```

So you can get an automobile implementation as follows:

```
    AutomobileFactory automobileFactory = new AutomobileFactory();
    IJeep jeep = automobileFactory.Create<IJeep>();

    jeep.Rename(new JeepRenameArgs());

    // or even:
    ICanRename<JeepRenameArgs> jeep2 = automobileFactory.Create<IJeep>() as ICanRename<JeepRenameArgs>;
    jeep2.Rename(new JeepRenameArgs());
```

See how I could rename a `Jeep` even without either knowing the implementation or its interface!

### Anyway...

It seems like you would end up re-inventing the wheel. Above code and even yours seems to be a basic inversion of control container service locator.

What about using something like [*Castle Windsor*](http://www.castleproject.org/)?

```
WindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Register
(
      Classes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<IAutomobile>()
                   .WithServiceAllInterfaces().LifestyleTransient()
);

IJeep jeep = container.Resolve<IJeep>();
```

Or, in order to don't going evil (you should avoid [service locator anti-pattern](http://designpattern.ninja/anti-pattern/software-architecture/dependency-injection/inversion-of-control/service-locator)), you should leverage [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection):

```
public class YourClass
{
      public YourClass(IJeep jeep)
      {
          Jeep = jeep;
      }

      private IJeep Jeep { get; }

      public void DoStuff()
      {
           Jeep.Rename(new JeepArgs());
      }
}
```

...and let the inversion of control container inject the required automobile implementation for you!